# Stripe.js - Cannot read property 'stripeToken' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate stripe.js into a web app I'm working on, however I'm being thrown the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'stripeToken' of undefined
```

The clientside is setting the hidden input of the token but for some reason, the server can't pull it this:

```
var stripeToken = request.body.stripeToken;
```

Any ides as to why this might be?

Client-side JS

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken({
      number: $('.card-number').val(),
      cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
      exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
      exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
    }, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  // Grab the form:
  var $form = $('#payment-form');
  if (response.error) { // Problem!

    // Show the errors on the form:
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

  } else { // Token was created!

    // Get the token ID:
    var token = response.id;

    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));

    // Submit the form:
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};

jQuery(function($) {
  $('[data-numeric]').payment('restrictNumeric');
  $('.cc-number').payment('formatCardNumber');
  $('.cc-exp').payment('formatCardExpiry');
  $('.cc-cvc').payment('formatCardCVC');
  $.fn.toggleInputError = function(erred) {
    this.parent('.form-group').toggleClass('has-error', erred);
    return this;
  };
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cardType = $.payment.cardType($('.cc-number').val());
    $('.cc-number').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardNumber($('.cc-number').val()));
    $('.cc-exp').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardExpiry($('.cc-exp').payment('cardExpiryVal')));
    $('.cc-cvc').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardCVC($('.cc-cvc').val(), cardType));
    $('.cc-brand').text(cardType);
    $('.validation').removeClass('text-danger text-success');
    $('.validation').addClass($('.has-error').length ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success');
  });
});
```

Server-side JS

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var stripeToken = request.body.stripeToken;

  var charge = stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 1000, // amount in cents, again
    currency: "usd",
    source: stripeToken,
    description: "Example charge"
  }, function(err, charge) {
    if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
      // The card has been declined
    }
  });
});
```

Form (jade)

```
 form(novalidate='', autocomplete='on', method='POST' id="payment-form")
  .form-group
    label.control-label(for='cc-number')
      | Card number formatting 
      small.text-muted
        | [
        span.cc-brand
        | ]
    input#cc-number.input-lg.form-control.cc-number(type='tel', autocomplete='cc-number', placeholder='•••• •••• •••• ••••', required='')
  .form-group
    label.control-label(for='cc-exp') Card expiry formatting
    input#cc-exp.input-lg.form-control.cc-exp(type='tel', autocomplete='cc-exp', placeholder='•• / ••', required='')
  .form-group
    label.control-label(for='cc-cvc') Card CVC formatting
    input#cc-cvc.input-lg.form-control.cc-cvc(type='tel', autocomplete='off', placeholder='•••', required='')
  button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary(type='submit' class='submit') Submit
  h2.validation
```

Comment: Your posted to `/` but have no output? `console.log` in your `app.post` post to make that's being hit and output something... Try identify if it's that call that is making it error. Also you would need to async and wait for stripe response before outputting a page.

Comment: The classes in my form and and the createToken function didn't match up, which was why it's failing. Now I'm being served `Cannot read property 'stripeToken' of undefined`. On to the next challenge!

Comment: your request is in the variable `req` not `request`

Comment: this `var stripeToken = request.body.stripeToken;`should be `var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;`

Comment: *Face palm. Thank you. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Happens to the best of us! Good luck, stripe is a great product :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

our request is in the variable `req` not `request`

this `var stripeToken = request.body.stripeToken;` should be `var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;`